What does this code from vim-dispatch do?
I was trying to rename mappings in vim-dispatch when I noticed the following in dispatch.vim:
nmap <script> <SID>:.    :<C-R>=getcmdline() =~ ',' ? "\0250" : ""<CR>

if !get(g:, 'dispatch_no_maps')
  call s:map('n', 'm<CR>',      '<SID>:.Make<CR>')
  call s:map('n', 'm<Space>',   '<SID>:.Make<Space>')

What does <SID>:. do and how is it usefull? What context does it affect? What is \0250?

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

hi @VivianDeSmedt no worries, I will not forget you :p . I am still thinking about the purpose or intention of the code. I am porting this to Lua to which-key.nvim to get some descriptions ( https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamilscripts/-/blob/master/nvim/lua/plugins.lua?ref_type=heads#L609 ) , and there is no equivalent I can see for <SID:., or is there? I should ask a separate question for that, it's making this one XY question.

I would propose to ask another question. We tend to discourage mega questions that are less useful to others. If the question is compact and the answer is compact it has more chance to be found and understood and to be reused to others.

The mapping defined is a <script> mapping.
Where <script> mapping only interfere with mapping defined within a given script (typically identified via the <SID> syntax).
More information with :help :map-script
In your example m<CR> will indirectly triggers the <SID>:. if/because both are defined within the same script.
Without the <script> and the <SID> the m<CR> could trigger :. mapping defined by other plugins or in other source file.
Remark: The "\0250" corresponds to "\<C-u>0". In this case if the command contains a range (i.e. it include an ,) then it will be replace by 0 (Ctrl u will kill the range and the 0 will replace it).

That is great and thank you, but what does it do? Is '<SID>:.Make<CR>' replaced by :<C-R>=getcmdline() =~ ',' ? "\0250" : ""<CR>Make<CR>? What does 0250 do there? I am more asking for interpretation, why would getcmdline "current command-line inputcontain,and why is it significant?:. mapping defined by other pluginsthat is true, but "normally":.Command` means to execute Commnad over the range of a current line number, right?

The "\0250" corresponds to "\<C-u>0"

Why does it correspond to it?  What does C-u (this is ctrl+u , right?) do?

Ctrl-u delete everything from the cursor position to the start of the line. It is quite usual in command line mapping (in particular to get rid of the range part somehow inserted when in usual mode but not only).

Och ok, so when I have something selected in visual mode, and I type :, it automatically becomes :'<,'>. Then getcmdline() =~ ',' is crude check to find a range in command line in the form of :<this>,<that> , and if such a range is found, then "\0250", which is "\<C-u>0", clears the command line till the beginning of the line and positions the cursor on zero position (the 0, right?), and after all that Make is called. Right?

Nearly I believe it will insert 0 as a range leading to :0Make if I understand correctly.
